# How do I turn an NSMutableData into an image in a view?

Tags: cocoa, nsdata

I downloaded a .jpg file from the Internet with this code:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cvcl.mit.edu/hybrid/cat2.jpg"]];
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain]; // etc etc
```

Everything works fine. I just don't know how to handle the data. Say I created an image view in IB, how would I go about displaying the image? Here's the last bit:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // ******do something with the data*********...but how  
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[receivedData length]);

    // release the connection, and the data object
    [connection release];
    [receivedData release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `NSImageView` is attached as an `IBOutlet` called `imageView` you should be able to initialize an image using the received data and then set the image view to display the image.

```
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:receivedData];
[imageView setImage:image];
[image release];
```

Answer (score 1):

UIImage has a method +imageWithData:

Comment: And if you need this on the Mac, use NSImage's initWithData: method.

Comment: aye.. whoops, was it a Mac question? I've been programming too long :)

Comment: There's no indication of whether it's a Mac or iPhone question.